# How to customise quick launch/left hand links on a subsite?

Tags: quick-launch

I am using SharePoint 2013 and I have create an enterprise wiki site as a subsite. I would like to edit the navigation links on the left hand side bar (aka quick launch) but I read that subsites will not have the "edit link" button for customization.

I have tried changing the settings under "site settings > navigation", but nothing changed.

*This is what I'm seeing on my subsite*

[image: This is what I'm seeing on my subsite]

*This is the "edit links" button I am referring to in the master site*

[image: This is the edit links button I am referring to in the master site]

If possible, I do not wish to go into codes editing. Please assist! Thanks!

Comment: Do you want custom menu on quick launch or just want to remove few links from it?

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Site Settings** >> Under Look and Feel click **Navigation** >> Under Structural Navigation: Sorting

[image]

Here you can change your **Current** and **Global** navigation settings.

Reference:

- http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/11/22/sharepoint-2013-addedit-links-in-quick-launch-or-left-navigation/
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Quick-Launch-for-site-navigation-d3288963-4a91-4470-9192-610952daecdf

Comment: I actually did this, but the changes does not show

Comment: Are you getting error? Or update your question with your steps that you have followed.

Comment: Nope, there is no error message. I edited the navigation just like your steps, but the changes does not reflect on the navigation sidebar.

Comment: Have you selected "Structural Navigation: Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings" option in "current navigation" in Navigation tab in site settings?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I still see the same thing on my sidebar